# Correct @elseif syntax in Blade of Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel-blade

Here is my code, I want to put an array of answers in just one @elseif line

```
 @if( $selectSummaryTable == 'MemType' )

                Summary of Members

 @elseif( $report_type == ['Category', 'CivilStatus'] )

                Baptism Report for {{ $report_date }}   

 @endif
```

How do you correctly put multiple values in the @elseif line?

Comment: OR do I have to do a long list off @elseifs?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function , change your code from

```
@elseif( $report_type == ['Category', 'CivilStatus'] )
```

to

```
@elseif(in_array($report_type,['Category', 'CivilStatus']))
```